# How do I get information from a database using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpass

I'm trying to create a login function that checks the password against the one I have stored in the database. I have used phpass to hash the password before it is entered if that is relevant. This is my code so far; obviously the check will not work because I have not pulled the $stored_hash from the database:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require "/home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/includes/PasswordHash.php";

if ($_POST){
$form = $_POST;
$username = $form['username'];
$password = $form['password'];
$hash_obj = new PasswordHash(8, false);
$passwordhash = $hash_obj->HashPassword($password);
$storedhash = this is where i need the code to pull the hashed password from the db;
try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phpproject', 'carl', 'pdt1848?');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
    catch(PODException $e){
        echo "Can't connect to the database";
    }
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=$username");



$check = CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash);
if($check){
    print_r("Registered user");
}
else{
    print_r("Not a registered user");
}


//login here
}
else{
?>
<form name="login" action="login.php" method="POST">
<label for "username">Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="username"/><br />
<label for "password">Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Are we to assume that `new PasswordHash(8, false);` is going to generate a non-unique 8 character string that will randomly match a previously generated `PasswordHash(8, false)`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That hashes their password they enter into their login form. It is a part of PHPass.

Comment: Change `WHERE username=$username")` to `WHERE username='$username'")` that variable needs to be wrapped in quotes. @carlgoodtoseeyou

Comment: the best way to hash is md5; but anyway PasswordHash(8, false) can give a good result

Comment: No, not MD5. @IlyasMimouni too old and too fast as a hash method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this quick resolve:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require "/home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/includes/PasswordHash.php";

if ($_POST){
$form = $_POST;
$username = $form['username'];
$password = $form['password'];
$hash_obj = new PasswordHash(8, false);
$passwordhash = $hash_obj->HashPassword($password);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=phpproject', 'carl', 'pdt1848?');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$response = $bdd->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");
$data=$response->fetch();
$stored_hash = $data['password'];

echo '<br>the password stored in the database is :'. $stored_hash.'<br>';

$check = CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash);
if($check){
    print_r("Registered user");
}
else{
    print_r("Not a registered user");
}


//login here
}
else{
?>
<form name="login" action="login.php" method="POST">
<label for "username">Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="username"/><br />
<label for "password">Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: After entering in the login information I am presented with this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'carlgoodtoseeyou' in 'where clause'' in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/forms/login.php:38 Stack trace: #0 /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/forms/login.php(38): PDO->query('SELECT password...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/carlton/public_html/PHPproject/forms/login.php on line 38